# Как читать последовательность строк, если не знаешь их количество?

Tags: c#, строки

Здраствуйте. Есть такая задача:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю количество передаваемых строк. Как читать эти строки через цикл в C#?

Comment: Файл что-ли читать надо, или в каком виде на вход подаются строки?

Comment: @Bulson если сайт дает данные не через файл, есть другие варианты читать?

Comment: А как сайт дает? `json` или `html`?

Comment: @Bulson По моему json.

Comment: Если json, то десериализуете и получаете перечисление `IEnumerable<T>`, который поддерживает цикл `foreach()`.

Comment: Явно же в задании написано, в каком формете входные данные - простой текст. При чем тут JSON? Чтобы точно ответить на ваш вопрос, надо знать, как вы эти данные получаете.

Comment: А зачем вам точное количество? Обрабатывайте строки по одной, поддерживайте текущие координаты.

Comment: @VladD а как узнать, что я дошел до конца?

Comment: @LeskhanMuratuly: Контрвопрос: а в каком виде к вам приходят строки? На stdin?

Comment: @VladD да, через стандартный поток ввода.

Comment: Сверху ошибся, извиняюсь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
while (true)
{
    var line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (line == null)
        break;
    // process line
}
```

Более изящный вариант такой. Определите вспомогательную функцию

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetLines(TextReader tr)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (tr.ReadLine() is { } line)
            yield return line;
        else
            yield break;
    }
}
```

и обрабатывайте строки в цикле так:

```
foreach (var line in GetLines(Console.In))
{
    // process line
}
```

Comment: спасибо)) Помогло.

Comment: @LeskhanMuratuly: Пожалуйста!